# PhpMyAdmin - connection was reset error

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error when I am trying to upload a backup of my site (.sql) in phpmyadmin. 
The size of file is 15 MB and after zipping it, its 9 MB.

Can anyone help me out with this.

I have already changed - 
max_execution_time = 8000
max_input_time = 8000
post_max_size = 8G
upload_max_filesize = 2G

Answer (score 1):

You might edited wrong php.ini file. Also, check the value of memory_limit.

It's also better if you can tell us more about the environment (E.g: RAM?)

Comment: I am using it on VPS. and the file that i edited was located at /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini.

The specs of VPS are 1 GB RAM and 30 GB space.

Comment: memory_limit = 8G

Comment: Which browser are you using? That can be caused by some browser extensions (E.g: Firebug in Firefox). Can u clear cache in browser, disable plugins one by one then try again? This might not relate to PHP/MySQL configurations.

Comment: Idid what you said but its still not working